# Best way to integrate solr with any data source

Tags: solr, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am working on migrating my old indexing tool to solr(version 7). But I am not so sure, how do I index my files to solr.

Data in our system are located at oracle DB, mysql and cassendra. But update in these DBs are not so frequent(2-3 times in 24 hrs) and these will be the source for my solr index files.

In one of the collections I will have around 300k-400k records and in another somewhere around 5k.

I could come up with 2 methods.

1. Create ETL pipeline from diff data source using apache Storm.
2. Use Kafka connect source and sink.

which among 2 is good for system like ours? or is both method overkill for system like ours?

Comment: Nifi or Streamsets might be better than manually writing Storm topologies, plus there's overlap with Kafka Connect for those databases

Answer (score 0):

The size of the data is small enough that just do whatever you're comfortable with - either use an existing tool or write a small indexer in a language you have experience with. There is no need to overthink this at that stage.

And outside of that - it's usually impossible to make a recommendation without have in depth knowledge of your situation, except for very specific questions.